# Permission in file using giving error

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a small snippet

`fd = open("data", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)` is giving me the permission wrongly.

When I did the `ls -l data` I got this
`-rw-------  1 mayukhsarkar  staff  0 Aug 17 11:44 data`

can some tell what's wrong?

**Note: In koding.com I am getting permission like this**
`-rw-r--r-- 1 mayukh mayukh 0 Aug 17 06:11 data`

*SOLVED: **umask(000)** before the open syscall did the trick*

Comment: can you tell what permission are showing after using umask(000)

Comment: and also please clarify me what is your intension behind your 3rd argument any specific reason ?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the mode incorrectly. It needs to be passed as a third argument:

```
open("data", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
```

Note that creating a file with `O_RDONLY` doesn't make a lot of sense, as you won't be able to write to it after creating it...

Comment: sorry even this solution gives me the same permissions even with `O_RDWR`

Comment: Absolutely correct: 1) The main problem is that you didn't specify the flags (`, 0666`), so you weren't setting any permissions.  2) I think you probably want these flags: `open("data", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);`.  The "man" page for open is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open).  Remember to delete your bogus file, and *always* check the error return from open()!  And, as arkascha points out, remember about [umask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Also note that the specified permissions are influenced by the currently active umask setting in your process.

Comment: I think you are right..It is because of umask.... Can you please tell me how to get around this prob...@arkascha..

Comment: @FoggyDay..Even with duskwuff answer it is the same

Comment: Yep, great you solved your issue. This is exactly the purpose of the umask: to control permissions used and granted by an application from outside the process. Have fun!

Comment: @arkascha At my office PC, I never needed the umask..I guess by default it is set to 000..although never checked.

Comment: Could be, then you should find out where the umask is set. Sounds like a default setting then for your system, probably set by some skeleton shell environment. Take a look around in `/etc/default` or `/etc/skeleton`, also the `~/.bash....` files. Depends a bit on your distribution.